# No se me renderiza una imagen en la barra de navegación y tengo la ruta de la imagen bien escrita. Estoy usando Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, angular, bootstrap, nav

lo que pasa es que estoy usando bootstrap en un proyecto con angular y quiero cambiar el icono por defecto que este le da al header de la pagina web. pero al agregar la imagen pues no se renderiza en el nav. Soy nuevo usando bootstrap. Agradezco mucho cualquier ayuda. Como pueden ver a lado de payment gateway Sasha no se renderiza la imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo que estoy usando para el nav:

```
<div class="d-flex flex-column flex-md-row align-items-center pb-3 mb-4 border-bottom">
  <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center text-dark text-decoration-none">
    <!--En este pequeño contenedor agrego la imagen que quiero como logo en el nav de la pagina:-->
    <div>
    <img src="../sources/icons/logo-sasha.png">
    </div>
    <span class="fs-4">payment gateway Sasha</span>
  </a>
  
  <nav class="d-inline-flex mt-2 mt-md-0 ms-md-auto">
    <a class="me-3 py-2 text-dark text-decoration-none" href="#">Features</a>
    <a class="me-3 py-2 text-dark text-decoration-none" href="#">Enterprise</a>
    <a class="me-3 py-2 text-dark text-decoration-none" href="#">Support</a>
    <a class="py-2 text-dark text-decoration-none" href="#">Pricing</a>
  </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: Eso es que no encuentra el icono, por eso aparece la imagen rota. Revisa bien el path. Es probable que debas usar ruta absoluta en este caso, pues eso se debe repetir en toda tu web que debe estar usando distintas urls, por lo tanto procura ponerlo sin los dos puntos y partiendo de la raiz de tu web, quizás así:  `<img src="/sources/icons/logo-sasha.png">` si es que se encuentra en tu `public_html/sources/icons/`

Comment: que te muestra la consola?

Comment: no te entiendo sobre cambiar el logo por defecto pero tene en cuenta que:` la clase .navbar-brand aplica estilo automatico
<nav>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
    <img src="../sources/icons/logo-sasha.png" alt="Logo" style="width:40px;">
</a>`